# A Scala/Java media framework?

Tags: java, swing, scala, media

I had the idea to start investigating in creating and using media components in Java but I didn't find any convincing framework. The two that I found were

- Java Media Framework (JMF) : it seems so powerful, not so fast but the last update was in 2003.
- Java Media Components (JMC) : from what I found, it's easier to use than JMF but it's more limited too.

So I just wanted to know wich of these frameworks should I choose ? Are there any other options ? And can they be used from a Scala-Swing application ?

Thanks

Comment: As I understand, you can use any Java framework from Scala.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528986/jmf-replacement

Answer (score 1):

In my experience all existing media frameworks for Java suck big time. 
What looks very promising in this area is JavaFX. And it integrates with Swing pretty well.
I have no doubt that it will work with Scala too (even though I haven't tried).

My suggestion would be to investigate JavaFX for any media related work for any JVM based languages.

Answer (score 0):

The JMF is easy to use, there's a book about JMF programming in pdf online google it and download it. It's very flexible and using JNI ( Java Native Interface ) you can created .d or .dll files and link them into the JNI JAR Class Library and then make your scala, c++, assembly code work, it works great with GNU C++, especially on the Cygwin platform.

Note JMF is 32-bit only, so download the 32-bit JRE and JDK for it.