# Playing video in Java

Tags: java, video, frameworks, media

I need to play a video in my JFrame. I've looked around and I have installed the Java media framework and I've tried numerous ways, media panel doesn't seem to work and I don't understand Player. If someone could tell me an easy way to play a video inside a JFrame or even which methods to call that would be great.

( I also have the .avi file in the same directory as the .class and .java files )

Answer (score 10):

#### JMF is <s>basically</s> dead.

I don't have first-hand experience with playing video with Swing, but [here's a list of alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives) to JMF you might try. There are also a number of SO questions about this already:

- [Video playback in Java ( JMF, Fobs4JMF, Xuggler, FMJ )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041871/video-playback-in-java-jmf-fobs4jmf-xuggler-fmj)
- [JMF replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528986/jmf-replacement)

Based on those, it looks like [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) is the solution.

Comment: Because **it is dead.** The [last version was released in 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework) - that's over 8 years ago at this point. What makes you think it's _not_ dead?

Comment: @ Matt Ball [can you answer this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885226/set-of-questions-related-to-playing-sound-video-in-java) Actually **I** was looking forward to it after reading about `Xuggler`

Answer (score 1):

For the casual reader, Xuggler is now **deprecated**. Use Humble video instead: https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video.

On the other hand, you can have a look at the [`vlcj`](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) project.
It permits you embedding a native VLC media player in a Java AWT Window or Swing JFrame.

**UPDATE Feb 04 '16**

- The Humble Video project seems inactive. There's no new updates since Janury the 3rd 2015.
- vlcj is still active. The last update was done on Feb 03 '16.