# forwarding and rewinding audio in xuggler

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, javasound, xuggle

I have used `xuggler` to play audio files other than `wav,au,aiff`. Since `xuggler` performs audio decoding at low level it is very hard to write a method that both forwards and rewinds the audio being played . *( while decoding xuggler analyzes each data packet and then sends it to play)*

One way could be read bunch of packets at a time and then send the next packet to play.This way the effect of forwarding audio can be felt . `But i don't know how to implement this method` Moreover this is not the best way i can forward the data.

**Are there any direct methods to forward and rewind audio ? If not direct what is the algorithm , steps to do this ?**

Comment: @ closer you find this question hard to understand ? I guess why everybody is trying to close down xuggle questions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the `seekKeyFrame()` method in `IContainer`? See [here](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer.html#seekKeyFrame%28int,%20long,%20int%29). On seek, you could just flush the dataline and then on execution of the method the container should jump to the given location.

If you want to do it by a percentage call, then [getDuration()](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer.html#getDuration%28%29) gets the entire length of the stream (if available.) You can then work out accurate timestamps from there.