# Embedding video in an AWT application

Tags: java, awt

I am working upon a java AWT application.I need to embed a video in the application.
How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play video in a Java Desktop Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598482/play-video-in-a-java-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm

Also this question has been asked and answered

[Playing video in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277921/playing-video-in-java)

[Play video in a Java Desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598482/play-video-in-a-java-desktop-application)