# Play video in Java graphics

Tags: java, swing, video, jframe

I need to play a video in my `JFrame` (specifically as a splash screen right when the program launches), however, all the research I have done have lead me to the Java media framework which is outdated.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277921/playing-video-in-java) that seems to have some solutions, but I didn't find a guide on how to do it. I am very bad at reading documentation, is there a step-by-step guide on how I could implement this in a good way?

Comment: Does your intro animation have sound?  If not, you probably want to convert it to an animated GIF that can be used for an actual [SplashScreen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).

Comment: @VGR that could be an option, although you lose a lot of quality when converting to a GIF. Is this easy to do with little knowledge?

Comment: It’s true you lose quality when converting to GIF, but how many colors does your animation have?  If it’s a splash screen animation, I doubt it has a complex background.  As for how to convert, I would [download ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and use a command like `ffmpeg -i animation.mp4 animation.gif`.  I’m sure there are other tools that can do it as well.

Comment: i’ll try. as for the implementation in Java, is that easy?

Comment: Yes, read the SplashScreen documentation to which I linked.